# ComplexInfinity for a convergent product

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerics, special-functions

The infinite product involving the ratio of (n^2)! to its Stirling approximation

```
  stirling[n_] := n^n/E^n*Sqrt[2*Pi*n];
  Product[(n^2)!/stirling[n^2], {n, 1, Infinity}]
```

converge to

```
  1.14426047263759216966268786792807358744778313849111...
```

But I get a following result

```
  NProduct[(n^2)!/stirling[n^2], {n, 1, Infinity}]
  (* ComplexInfinity *)
```

Why ?

Comment: It applies a form of the ratio test (on $(a_{n+1}-1)/(a_n-1)$, and for some reason, `Limit` comes up with `-17` instead of `1` (http://i.stack.imgur.com/wGm4n.png).  Looks like a bug.

Answer (score 3):

#### Analysis of the error (bug?)

We can see from the trace below that the second limit, which carries out a ratio test for the product, mistakenly yields `-17` (which would indicate divergence, if correct).

```
Trace[
 NProduct[(n^2)!/stirling[n^2], {n, 1, Infinity}],
 _Limit,
 TraceInternal -> True, TraceForward -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There might have been some assumptions added to `$Assumptions` internally, but we can test the limit directly.  Indeed, it's still wrong.

```
Limit[(-1 + (E^(1 + n)^2 ((1 + n)^2)^(-(1/2) - (1 + n)^2) ((1 + n)^2)!)/Sqrt[2 π]) / 
   (-1 + (E^n^2 (n^2)^(-(1/2) - n^2) (n^2)!)/Sqrt[2 π]), 
 n -> Infinity, Assumptions -> True]
(*  -17  *)
```

We can take a look numerically.  One problem is that the terms and factors quickly become very large, evaluating to `Overflow[]` and `Underflow[]` if you push `n` too large.  However, with a larger `WorkingPrecision`, the other default settings yield a result close to `1`.

```
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"];
NLimit[
 (-1 + (E^(1 + n)^2 ((1 + n)^2)^(-(1/2) - (1 + n)^2) ((1 + n)^2)!)/Sqrt[2 π]) /
   (-1 + (E^n^2 (n^2)^(-(1/2) - n^2) (n^2)!)/Sqrt[2 π]), 
 n -> ∞, WorkingPrecision -> 50]
(*  1.00000010179494085  *)
```

Interestingly, `Series[]` gets is right. Somewhat odd, because I thought `Limit` uses `Series[]`, at least sometimes.  (If you trace the internal machinations of the `Limit` aboe, the `-17` just shows up and `Series` is not used.  The trace is relatively short, so it's feasible to inspect it. I can't see how the `-17` is computed.  I suspect it's a bug.)

```
Series[
 (-1 + (E^(1 + n)^2 ((1 + n)^2)^(-(1/2) - (1 + n)^2) ((1 + n)^2)!)/Sqrt[2 π]) /
   (-1 + (E^n^2 (n^2)^(-(1/2) - n^2) (n^2)!)/Sqrt[2 π]),
 {n, Infinity, 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

#### A workaround

A workaround is to turn off convergence checking.

```
NProduct[(n^2)!/stirling[n^2], {n, 1, Infinity}, 
 VerifyConvergence -> False, Method -> "EulerMaclaurin"]
```

> NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in n near {n} = {2003.19}. NIntegrate obtained 0.005177154456675506 and 0.00001444866795796547 for the integral and error estimates. >>
>
> NProduct::emcon: Euler-Maclaurin sum failed to converge to requested error tolerance. >>

```
(*  1.144224800063829`  *)
```

Comment: In 5.2, the ratio test limit gives $-11$ instead of $-17$; this seems to be a long standing bug.